# make uitableview cell height decided by the automatic height of the cell content when searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITable view and a search bar, the thing is if it's in normal state(non-searching mode) the height of each row is static

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 78.0;
}
```

And when the state changes to searching the cell height should be decided by the actual content, so how can I tell the table view that?

I try to do this like:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text change - %d",self.searching);

    //Remove all objects first.
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        self.searching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        // try to do it with this, not working
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else {
        self.searching = NO;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;//78.0;
}
```

try this for row height

Comment: first estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath takes your cell height and than heightForRowAtIndexPath set UITableViewAutomaticDimension which is your estimated height

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension is your cell height whatever it is